# Should I install VNC server for Gnome if I am using Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome

I am using Ubuntu v. 16.04.  I see that one of the items that has appeared in my Ubuntu Software updater is as above. Should I be installing it or is it only for Gnome?  I am using Unity.

Comment: I highly recommend `x11vnc` as Zacharee1 said. Follow this guide http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8361 (it's the same procedure for 15.04,1 5.10 and 16.04). It works perfectly without bugs and the parameters this tutorial is using, allow you to logout and login again without problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is made for GNOME, so I would normally say it might work an it might not and you might as well try it out. However, one of the reviewers seems to be using Unity, and has left a bad review:

> The default remote desktop doesn't work with compiz and Unity, after trying in many systems, you can connect to the computer, but you just see a freeze image. Try using x11vnc or even better NoMachineNX for remote desktop

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/vino/

Now, that was for 11.04, so maybe things have changed and it works on Unity now. But, looking at the other reviews, and seeing reports that it's a pretty resource intensive app for what it does, I think you should follow the recommendations in the reviews and try RealVNC or RDP instead.